# How to detect running program and ask to close it from VS Msi project?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, windows-installer

I have a simple Visual Studio MSI project.

I want to HALT the installation if I detect a running program of a certain type (e.g. "aaa.exe") and wait until the user closes it before proceeding.

how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, have you considered the [Restart Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372466(VS.85).aspx)?

> Applications that use Windows
>   Installer 4.0 for installation and
>   servicing on Windows Vista
>   automatically use the Restart Manager
>   to reduce system restarts. The default
>   behavior on Windows Vista is to shut
>   down applications rather than shut
>   down and restart the operating system
>   whenever possible. In cases where a
>   system restart is unavoidable,
>   installers can use the Restart Manager
>   API to schedule restarts in such a way
>   that it minimizes the disruption of
>   the user's work flow.

Restart Manager should automatically detect open files/handles-to-files that are are going to be updated by the .MSI and gracefully stop/restart them.